# How to get the returned value of the event listener keyboardframechanged in Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: javascript, events, titanium, appcelerator

In this link [Titanium.App-event-keyboardframechanged](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-keyboardframechanged) it says that : " The event returns the dictionary containing keyboardFrame.x", I am new in programming so I want to know how to get keyboardFrame.width from this event, here is the code:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("keyboardframechanged",function(e){alert("keyboard changed");});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("keyboardframechanged",function(e){
    alert( e.width );
    alert( e.keyboardFrame.width );       
});
```

One of the 2 alerts must work

Cheers

Comment: `Ti.App.addEventListener("keyboardframechanged",function(e){
   alert( e.keyboardFrame.width );       
});`

worked perfectly thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know JS, you can't return values for handler/callback functions. However, they usually provide the values via the event object, which would be `e` inside the function. Try inspecting what `e` contains.

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("keyboardframechanged",function(e){
  //something like e.keyboardFrame.x
});
```